# Savon 2 plain xml requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, soap, savon

Is there a way I can use savon to generate a plain xml request from a hash, with no soap envelope and body tags?

The only way I've found to do this so far is directly passing in raw xml using `Savon.client.call(:some_action, xml: '<myxml />')`

Comment: What do mean by "with no soap envelope and body tags?" *A SOAP message MUST use the SOAP Envelope namespace* other wise it will not be valid soap request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nokogiri - which is a dependency of Savon.